# Wildcard returning multiple items EnumerateFiles. Need to be more specific

Tags: c#, enumeration

I have a directory of pdfs.

I need to grab these pdfs based off of a number and currently have this:

```
var complianceFiles = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(complianceDocumentPath, salesOrder.CustomerNumber + "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

If I have two customers that contain similar customer numbers (i.e. 1234 and 12345) it is returning both. I should note that the documents contain the number, as well as a unique title.

I know the issue is with my search pattern, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `*` also matches `5`.  What are your filenames?

Comment: Show some sample file names from multiple customers.

Comment: Look at what the search string looks like when using customer 1234: "1234*.*" This will find anything that starts with 1234, which is exactly what you're getting. I, too, would like to see the file names.

Comment: Better put some separator between the customer number and the rest of the file name when creating the files on disk. Something like "1234.title text.dat", then you would be able to get only the needed files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine the search pattern with LINQ:

```
var complianceFiles = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    complianceDocumentPath,
    salesOrder.CustomerNumber + "*.pdf", 
    System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
    ).Where(path => Path.GetFileName(path)
        .TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Count() == 
            Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(salesOrder.CustomerNumber)));
```

This checks if the number of consecutive digits in the file-name is exactly the length of `salesOrder.CustomerNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

EnumerateFiles supports only * and ? as wildcard characters. * is for zero or more characters. ? - exactly one character.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd413233.aspx

If you want to be more specific, try @CodeBeard solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to filter the filenames at that point, I would recommend using Linq to filter them afterwards. That way you can more easily use a regular expression match to filter the file names.

Pseudo-code:

```
var wantedfiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(complianceDocumentPath,"*.*",etc...)
                  .Where(f=>Regex.Match(f.Name,"pattern with salesOrder.CustomerNumber"))
```